# How do you write exp(a/b) in C#?

Tags: c#, math

I am calculating a formula and would like to know how to write `exp(a/b)` in C#.
I heard about `math.exp`, but it takes only one parameter.

Answer (score 8):

As it says in the docs for Math.Exp,

> Use the Pow method to calculate powers
>   of other bases.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

If you're passing the result of a/b (that is, a divided by b), then that result is a single value, which could be passed to Math.Exp.

Answer (score 7):

Like Daniel already mentioned in his answer, use `Math.Exp`.

With my answer, I'd like to point out a little pitfall that you can avoid in your situation.

If you're going to call `Math.Exp` like you mentioned in your question, i.e. `Math.Exp(a/b)`, where `a` and `b` are two integers, and not variables, don't forget to cast the numerator to `double`:

```
Math.Exp((double)1/2);
```

If you don't do that, the division will be made with two `int`s, resulting in a loss of precision (see the comments in the code):

```
Math.Exp(1/2); //results in 1, since 1/2 = 0 and e^0 = 1
Math.Exp((double)1/2); //results in 1.64872127070013, since (double)1/2 = 0.5
```

As Daniel correctly mentioned in a comment to this answer, the cast to `double` can be omitted once you define `a` and `b` as `double`, and use both variables for the division in `Math.Exp`:

```
double a = 1;
double b = 2;
Math.Exp(a/b);
```

Comment: NB. only add the cast if `a` and `b` are not of type `double` already.

Comment: @Daniel True, thanks. I've updated my answer to include your remark, though I was assuming he would call it without defining variables